# C++ Incrementing a Pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, post-increment, pre-increment

Why can I do something like *x = *x+1;, but doing something like *x = *x++; doesn't seem to have any affect?

Code:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void doSomething(int *x, int *y)
{
    *x = *x++;
    *y = *y + 5;
}

int main()
{
    int x = 4;
    int y = 3;
    doSomething(&x, &y);
    cout << "x is now: " << x << endl; //outputs 4
    cout << "y is now: " << y << endl; //outputs 8
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're not "incrementing a pointer", you're "incrementing a thing pointed to by a pointer".

Comment: What about trying `++*x`?

Comment: I am not sure why this is getting down voted.  I was following alongside this video @ 31:25 is the reference to the code above:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rxvv9krECNw

Comment: Utterly off topic grammar correction: effect, not affect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This statement

```
*x = *x+1;
```

can be written like

```
*x = ++*x;
```

Of course you could just write

```
++*x;
```

As for this statement

```
*x = *x++;
```

then it is equivalent to

```
*x = *( x++ );
```

and has undefined behavior because the side effect of the post-increment operator is not sequenced.

Comment: `*x = ++*x` is also UB.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: It would be UB in C++03, but I'm unsure about C++11. There's something about sequenced before for =.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf In C++ 11 such expression-statement was adopted as valid.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know the behaviour changed in C++11.  At any rate, there's still a large chunk of the world where that *is* UB (and either way, is likely to cause confusion/distrust amongst readers).  Why isn't the suggestion to just write `++*x;`?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I showed how it can be written correctly using increment operators as the author wants.

Answer (score 2):

The postfix operator `++` has a higher precedence from the `dereference *` operator. The statement `*x = *x++;` is executed as follows `*x = (*(x++))`

As you can see the `++` operator is executed first making the pointer point to where it was pointing. From there, the `dereference` operator is executed. If you want to increment the actual value of `x` just write `++*x;`

Comment: The expression result of `x++` is the original value of `x`.

Answer (score -1):

Because all expressions follow [operators precedence rule](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

As you can see in the table the operator `operator++` has higher precedence than `operator*`

You can better follow with parenthesis, the code:

```
*x = *x++;
```

is equivalent to:

```
*x = *(x++);
```

In short, you're incrementing the value of the pointer and *after* you dereference it.

In memory it happens something like:

```
|  x = 4   |     <---- &x
|  trash   |
|  trash   |
```

You increment the pointer which will points the next cell in the memory:

```
|  x = 4   |     
|  trash   |     <---- &x+1
|  trash   |
```

And with assign its value to itself, anyway it's trash.

---

## Solution

In order to avoid miss-understanding the usage of parenthesis should be a valid help.

Fix it with:

```
*x = ++(*x);
```

Comment: `*x = (*x)++;` and now you have *another* problem. What about just `(*x)++;`?

Comment: @BoPersson Sorry too fast, I fixed

Comment: _"you're incrementing the value of the pointer and after you dereference it"_. Is that true? The increment is a side effect that could happen before or after the assignment.  My understanding is that `*x++` will always dereference `x`'s original position, then later `x` will move to point to the next position. So the result is undefined? Maybe the trash location gets the value of 4 assigned?